# DB2 SQLCODE -904 when unloading table using JCL

Tags: sql, db2, jcl

While i was unloading table using JCL , i Got this error :

> UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY AN UNAVAILABLE RESOURCE

But the table exist in Database and even available, at the beginning it works but when i repeated the process of unloading several times it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to include your JCL and Control Cards, and the full sysout from the step. Explain what worked the first time. Have you looked up the message? From your comments, I'd think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that if you look at the output of your unload job, you will see that the table is in either `Check Pending` or `Copy Pending` status. It's impossible to tell without more information, though.

To fix this you (or your DBA) will need to run a [Repair Utility](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.ugref/src/tpc/db2z_repairsyntax.dita) to get it out of that status.

You can see [this thread on IBMMainframe.com](http://ibmmainframes.com/about79.html) for some more information about both statuses.